# Update object in array with handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional `Item` component that uses `React.memo`. The component renders a few different input fields. I'm trying to update the state value for the changed `Item` but I am not sure how to do that without mutating or changing the current state since my original implementation caused `nextProps` and `prevProps` for `React.memo` to be the same.

Here is my handler in the parent container component:

```
handleItemChange = (item, event, index) => {

    item[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      job: this.state.job
    })

}
```

My state looks something like this:

```
this.state = {
    job: {
        items: [{id: 1, quantity: 3, name: "test"}, {id: 2, quantity: 1, name: "test 2"}, {id: 3, quantity: 1, name: "test 3"}]
    }
}
```

In my form component, I render a list of `Items` like this:

```
{this.props.job.items.map((i, index) => (
    <Item key={i.id} handleItemChange={this.props.handleItemChange} item={i} index={index} />
 ))}
```

Then, in my `Item` component (that's memoized) I  render the input fields and call the handler:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {

  console.log(prevProps.job_item.quantity)
  console.log(nextProps.job_item.quantity)

  return true
};

const Item = React.memo(props => {

  return (


    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={1}>
          <FormControl>
            <TextField
              name="quantity"
              value={props.item.quantity}
              label="quantity"
              variant="outlined"
              type="number"
              onChange={e => props.handleItemChange(props.item, e, props.index)}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>



  )

}, areEqual);

export default Item;
```

With this current code, both prop objects in `areEqual` contain identical values and I believe this is because I am changing the `item` directly in the `handleItemChange` handler but I'm not sure how to change the item value without referencing it directly. I looked at making a deep copy of the array object, but I'm not sure how to do that. I am also passing the index value so referencing `this.state.job.items[index]` is possible for my case.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```js
handleItemChange = (item, event, index) => {
  // copy the state, since state should be immutable
  let clonedJob = [...this.state.job];

  // Find item in new state
  let clonedItem = clonedJob.find(i => return i.id === item.id);

  // Update that cloned item
  clonedItem[event.target.name] = event.target.value;

  // Update state
  this.setState({
    job: clonedJob
  })
}
```